# How to create Performance testing framework in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

For functional automation we use to create a framework which is reusable for automating application. Is there any way to create Performance testing framework in jmeter. So that we can use same framework for Performance testing of different applications.

Please help if any one knows and provide more information regarding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider JMeter as a "framework" which already comes with test elements to [build requests via different protocols/transports](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers), applying [assertions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#assertions), [generating reports](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html), etc.

It is highly unlikely you will be able to re-use existing script for another application as JMeter acts on protocol level therefore there will be different requests for different applications.

There is a mechanism in JMeter allowing to re-use pieces of test plan as modules so you won't have to duplicate your code, check out [Test Fragments](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#test_fragments) and [Module Controller](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421345-Using-JMeter-Module-Controller), however it is more applicable for a single application.

The only "framework-like" approach I can think of is adding your JMeter tests into continuous integration process so you will have a build step which will execute performance tests and publish reports, basically you will be able to re-use the same test setup and reporting routine and the only thing which will change from application to application will be .jmx test script(s). See [JMeter Maven Plugin](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin) and/or [JMeter Ant Task](https://github.com/jfifield/ant-jmeter) for more details.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. It is really helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

You must first ask yourself, how dynamic is my conversation that I am attempting to replicate.  If you have a very stable services API where the exposed external interface is static, but the code to handle it on the back end is changing, then you have a good shot at building something which has a long life.

But, if you are like the majority of web sites in the universe then you are dealing with developers who are always changing something, adding a resource, adding of deleting form values (hidden or not), headers, etc....  In this case you should consider that your scripts are perishable, with a limited life, and you will need to rebuild them at some point.

Having noted the limited lifetime of a piece of code to test a piece of code with a limited lifetime, are there some techniques you can use to insulate yourself?  Yes.  Rule of thumb is the higher up the stack you go to build your test scripts the more insulated you are from changes under the covers ( assuming the layer you build to is stable ).  The trade off is with more of the intelligence under the covers of your test interface, the higher the resource cost for any individual virtual user which then dictates more hosts for test execution and more skew from client side code which can distort the view of what is coming from the server.   An example, run a selenium script instead of a base jmeter script.  A browser is invoked, you have the benefit of all of the local javascript processing to handle the dynamic changes and your script has a longer life.